# How to exclude package from scoverage in maven

Tags: maven, scoverage

I am using scoverage-maven-plugin. What settings i need to provide in pom.xml to exclude package from scoverage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem can be fixed by adding :

```
<excludedPackages>your.package.here</excludedPackages>
```

inside the `<configuration>` tag in your "scoverage-maven-plugin".

Below example can be seen for reference:

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
       <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.0</version>
       <configuration>
             <excludedPackages>com.demoproject.utils</excludedPackages>
             <scalaVersion>2.11.8</scalaVersion>
             <highlighting>true</highlighting>
             <minimumCoverage>90</minimumCoverage>
             <failOnMinimumCoverage>true</failOnMinimumCoverage>
             <aggregate>true</aggregate>
       </configuration>
 </plugin>
```